# Return a reference to a member iterator

Tags: rust

I have a struct that has an iterator over a borrowed slice, and I want to create a method that returns an iterator that does some computation on the contained iterator

Basically this:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo<'a>  {
    inner: ::std::iter::Cycle<::std::slice::Iter<'a, u8>>,
}


impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn new<T: AsRef<[u8]> + ?Sized>(vals: &'a T) -> Foo<'a> {
        Self {
            inner: vals.as_ref().iter().cycle(),
        }
    }
    pub fn iter(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a {
        self.inner.by_ref().map(Clone::clone) // simple case but this could be any computation
    }
}
```

Which yields a cryptic error.

Here's my understanding: I need to bind the returned iterator's lifetime to the `&mut self` of `iter()` so that `&mut self` is only dropped when `.collect()` is called on the returned iterator.

BUT, changing to `fn iter(&'a mut self)` isn't good enough because `&'a mut self` now lives for the entire duration of the struct instance (meaning that calling `collect()` doesn't drop that reference). Which prevents something like this

```rust
#[test]
fn test(){
    let mut foo = Foo::new("hello, there");
    foo.iter().zip(0..4).collect::<Vec<_>>(); // call once, ok
    foo.iter().zip(0..4).collect::<Vec<_>>(); // error because 2 &mut references exist at the same
}
```

rust playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5511f380794c9818d03953032561c80c)

Comment: If, instead of defining the type of `inner` in the struct definition such that the struct gets parameterised by `'a`, you could just [make the type of `inner` generic](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bc1c4b9822542199babb56d448229058).

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is to make a struct just for iterating over those items. It makes things much easier.

```rust
    ...

    pub fn iter(&mut self) -> ClonedFooIter<'a, '_> {
        ClonedFooIter {
            inner: &mut self.inner,
        }
    }
}

pub struct ClonedFooIter<'a, 'b> {
    inner: &'b mut std::iter::Cycle<::std::slice::Iter<'a, u8>>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> Iterator for ClonedFooIter<'a, 'b> {
    type Item = u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.inner.next().cloned()
    }
}
```

The idea is that the returned struct only lives till the mutable borrow of `self` lives.

Using a struct makes naming the iterator type easier too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, unfortunately cloning doesn't quite work for my use-case, as I need  `inner` to be stateful